# UK standard visitor visa sponsored by my mother

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I want to visit the UK. I want to show my mother's Fixed Deposit account. Can I use that? Will my visa be rejected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: Is your mother sponsoring your visit? If not, then no, you can’t.

Comment: _"Will my visa get reject?"_ Your visa depends on many more things than your mother's bank account. We have no way to know.

Comment: Traveller Yes my mother will sponsor me.

Answer (score 1):

The UK Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules on funds, maintenance and accommodation provided by a third party state that:
V 4.3 A visitor’s travel, maintenance and accommodation may be provided by a third party where the decision maker is satisfied that they:
(a) have a genuine professional or personal relationship with the visitor; and
(b) are not, or will not be, in breach of UK immigration laws at the time of decision or the visitor’s entry to the UK; and
(c) can and will provide support to the visitor for the intended duration of their stay.

Therefore you can use your mother’s Fixed Deposit account provided it meets (c) above e.g. there are no restrictions on withdrawals from the account that would mean the funds would not be available to you during your visit. You will also need to provide evidence showing the source of the funds in the Fixed Deposit account.

As the applicant, you still have to show that you meet the requirements in your own right. Needing a sponsor may increase the likelihood of rejection.

Comment: Traveller thank you so much.your answer clear everything.But if you kindly explain me that,my mom got this money by selling her property so how can I show that as source of the fixed deposit?

Comment: @rudro You can provide evidence of the sale - the legal contract for example.